# Jenkins Shared Library: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I try to dynamically load a shared library in jenkins, hosted on github as follows

```
library identifier: 'custom-lib@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: 'ssh://git@github.com:papanito/jenkins-pipeline-helper.git',
   credentialsId: 'git'])
```

However, this fails with the following error

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote -h -t git@github.com:papanito/jenkins-pipeline-helper.git" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

The credential I am using has a valid private key and works fine when I use the library via Jenkins Settings. However loading it dynamically in the pipeline does not work. Any clue why?

Comment: It has to be an issue with the ssh settings. Are you using the very same machine for loading the lib and cloning the source code repositories? Did you configure anything specific regarding to ssh like HOME or GIT_SSH?

Comment: Yes I am using the same machine for loading lib and cloning the repo. No I did not configure anything regarding HOME or GIT_SSH

Comment: If you loaded the library in the settings like you said, then you can load it in the pipeline with `@Library('custom-lib')` or  `library('custom-lib')` instead.

Comment: Yes the call `@Library('custom-lib') _` works having the library registered under Global Pipeline Libraries. There I have no credentials defined

Comment: In my case it was caused by: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43802. After changing ModerSCM to LegacySCM it works as expected.

Comment: @matt schuchard you are right the import statement is different. I missed to describe that, however my point was that it did not work the dynamic way why otherwise it was working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently something wrong with the key. I've re-added the key to the credential store of jenkins, turns out now it work.

Answer (score 1):

Just move ur key into a folder and give the folder chmod 600 level access. And then add the key from that folder. Ssh-add should work for you.

Comment: Thanks but I really would like to use the credential store from jenkins